# Is this possible to convert DITA to Word process using Oxygen

Tags: docx, dita, oxygenxml, dita-ot

I'm trying to convert DITA to word process in oxygen by using the plugin name called **com.elovirta.ooxml**  through [this](https://github.com/jelovirt/com.elovirta.ooxml) link,

My Input Dita xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "urn:pubid:doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic>
  <title>Grade 2</title>
  <body>
    <section><title>Grade 2</title>
<p outputclass="SC_P_Large_Center">Grade 2 Module 1</p>
<p outputclass="SC_P_Large_Center">Literacy Labs</p>
<p outputclass="SC_P_Large_Center">Student  Notebook</p></section>
  </body>
</topic>
```

I'm tried through DITA-OT 2.1.0 and 1.8.5, but I'm getting the below errors
[image]

[image]

Please provide the suggestions for this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're using at least one DITA-OT plugin, that uses a pre-processing extension point. The message

```
Target "move-links"does not exist in the project "DOST".
It is used from target "dc-preprocess".
```

mentions the target `"dc-preprocess"`, which is not part of the core OT. Probably this is related to your problem.

I recommend to you to get a new toolkit and only install the **com.elovirta.ooxml** plugin. Then test again with your files. If this works, than you should debug your targets.

If you create a DITA-OT plugin that uses a pre-processing extension point, this extension point usage is global. It is not limited to the scope of this plugin and its transtypes. You can check, whether a pre-processing extension point is used by looking at the **plugin.xml** files of your plugins and searching for `depend.preprocess`.

```
<feature extension="depend.preprocess.post" value="my-target"/>
```

If you have a pre-processing target that should only be called for specific transtypes, you should use an Ant property, that has to be available before calling it.

```
<target name="my-target" if="mandatory.property">
  ...
</target>
```

Comment: After adding ''feature'' tag which you have provided we are getting this error in oxygen: 

docx.convert:
 [pipeline] [DOTJ025E][ERROR] The input to the "topic merge" transform process could not be found. Correct any earlier transform errors and try the build again, or see the DITA-OT User Guide for additional causes.

build.xml:41: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\DITA-OT\dita-ot-2.1.0-dita2word\plugins\com.elovirta.ooxml\build.xml:56: input file E:\Vinod\dec\30-12\temp\docx\oxygen_dita_temp\${dita.map.filename.root}_MERGED.xml does not exist

Comment: No, I did not meant you should add it. I meant, you probably already have such a <feature> element in another plugin. Search for "dc-preprocess" in your DITA-OT.

Comment: But first get a new DITA-OT, only install com.elovirta.ooxml and that try to use this to make sure, that no other plugin interferes with the dita2word transformation.

Comment: Yes I have taken new DITA OT 2.1.0 and installed only com.elovirta.ooxml with default plugins in DITA OT same  ''[pipeline] [DOTJ025E][ERROR]'' showing in oxygen and i Have searched "dc-preprocess" in my DITA-OT i founded in preprocess-extensions.xml next process what I can do, to resolve that error please guide us. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use the latest OT, which is 2.4.1 ATM, with the latest com.elovirta.ooxml and without any other plugins installed.You can prevent the preprocessing target to be called by searching for an Ant property, like I have shown in my example: if="mandatory.property"

Please read the DITA-OT docs first and try yourself. If you're stuck, feel free to ask, but you have to solve your problem yourself. I only can guide you. All depends on your environment.